# Gorm Preload convert key reference to string/integer

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using Gorm and DB driver PostgreSQL and i have struct like this :

**Projects**

```
type Project struct {
    ID              int       
    ListingOrigin         *ListingOrigin `gorm:"foreignkey:ListingID"`
}

func (Project) TableName() string {
    return "project.projects"
}
```

**ListingOrigin**

```
type ListingOrigin struct {
    ID int 
    ListingID string   `gorm:"not null"`
    OriginID  uint     `gorm:"not null"`
    Project   *Project `gorm:"foreignKey:ListingID;references:id"`
}

func (l *ListingOrigin) TableName() string {
    return "listing_origins"
}
```

As u can see we can do Preload using ID on table Project, but first, I need to convert that value to string or integer.

When I do like this :

```
    func (r *ProjectRepository) Options() (result []model.Project, err error) {
    var projects []model.Project
    query := r.db.Model(projects).Preload("ListingOrigin")

    query.Order("name asc")

    err = query.Find(&projects).Error

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return projects, nil
}
```

the error occurred :

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer (SQLSTATE 42883)
> [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "listing_origins" WHERE "listing_origins"."listing_id" IN (1,3,4) AND "listing_origins"."deleted_at" IS NULL

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Have you called `db.Automigrate` in first app open? Because I'm OK with your code, listing_id in database is already int8. And if I change it manually to varchar it will be error.

Comment: listing_id on table listing_origins is a string which mean is a text/varchar, so we need to convert ProjectID (int) to listing_id (string)

Comment: do you call gorm automigrate in your app?

Comment: iam not use automigrate in my app @RahmatFathoni